# Save access to this scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have color stored in a data attribute on my button that I wanted to use in a toggle. However, when I tried to access the data information using `this`, no data was available. How can I keep my access to the correct `this` scope?

I was trying to only toggle the given color for the elements which didn't contain Skip.

*html*

```
<div>
 <input id="toggleButton" type="button" value="Toggle" data-color="Red" />
</div>
<div id="toggleSet">
<div>Element</div>
 <div>Skip</div>
 <div>Element</div>
</div>
```

*css*

```
.ActivateRed{ color: red; }
```

*js*

```
$('#toggleButton').click(function(){
 $("#toggleSet div").each(function(index,element){
  if( element.innerHTML != "Skip" ){
   $(element).toggleClass("Activate"+$(this).data("color"));
                                       //^this has no data to access?
                                       //Why am I getting undefined?
  }
 });
});
```

Here is a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C9nRn/)** of my attempt. I keep getting `Activateundefined` as the class name. Why isn't `this` accessing my toggleButton's data?

Comment: I have seen a number of questions regarding a problem where saving the value of `this` is the solution to the problem. However, I could not find a canonical answer which explained what was wrong with using `this` in that fashion. Most answers were single line answers suggesting to store `var that = this` and move on. In order to try to reduce the amount of time people have to answer these types of questions I hoped to provide a canonical answer here. Please edit or request changes to it if anything is either incomplete or in need of correction.

Comment: I though [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) was the (non-jQuery-specific) canonical question. Not sure whether it would help to merge them.

Comment: @Bergi - I was trying to specifically address the jQuery aspect of how `this` is used with this type of structure. jQuery tends to obfuscate it a little and so I was attempting to explain the process involved. I think that the linked question from Felix addresses the non-jQuery aspect very well.

Comment: @TravisJ - `this` in JavaScript changes in different locations. It can also be changed programmatically via `.apply` or `.call`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - You are correct. In fact, that is part of what jQuery obfuscates by design. Internally jQuery will call `apply` on callback functions in order to bind `this` to the current element. I outline this in the answer below.

Comment: @TravisJ - Oops I just realized you wrote both the answer and the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Explanation of the problem

*this changed*

The value of **[`this`<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)** has changed and is no longer referencing the expected element or value. Often this is because the scope has changed, and as a result so has the `this` reference.

*this is contained in an execution context*

The scope refers to the current **[Execution Context<sup>ECMA</sup>](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3)**. In order to understand why `this` has changed, it is important to understand the way these execution contexts operate in JavaScript.

*execution contexts bind this*

When control enters an execution context (code is being executed in that scope) the environment for variables are setup (Lexical and Variable Environments - essentially this sets up an area for variables to enter which were already accessible, and an area for local variables to be stored), and the binding of `this` occurs.

*the this binding was changed for the execution context*

These contexts form a logical stack. The result is that contexts deeper in the stack have access to previous variables, but their bindings may have been altered. Every time jQuery calls a callback function, it alters the this binding by using **[`apply`<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)**.

```
callback.apply( obj[ i ] )//where obj[i] is the current element
```

The result of calling `apply` is that inside of jQuery callback functions, `this` refers to the current element being used by the callback function.

For example, in `.each`, the callback function commonly used allows for `.each(function(index,element){/*scope*/})`. In that scope, `this == element` is true. The consequence of that, is if you expected a previous `this` to be available, it will be bound to a different element.

### Brief explanation of `this` in jQuery callbacks

As shown above, jQuery callbacks use the apply function to bind the function being called with the current element. This element comes from the jQuery object's element array. Each jQuery object constructed contains an array of elements which match the **[selector<sup>jQuery API</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)** that was used to instantiate the jQuery object.

`$(selector)` calls the jQuery function (remember that `$` is a reference to `jQuery`, code: `window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;`). Internally, the jQuery function instantiates a function object. So while it may not be immediately obvious, using `$()` internally uses `new jQuery()`. Part of the construction of this jQuery object is to find all matches of the selector. The jQuery object then contains an array-like structure of the DOM elements matching the selector.

When a jQuery api function is called, it will internally iterate over this array-like structure. For each item in the array, it calls the callback function for the api, binding the callback's `this` to the current element. This call can be seen in the code snippet above where `obj` is the array-like structure, and `i` is the iterator used for the position in the array of the current element.

### Finding a solution

It can be hard to determine what happened since jQuery tends to fail silently. **[`.data()`<sup>jQuery API</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/data/)** is still a valid call here, it just returns `undefined`. As a result, the above code produces a class name of "Activate"+undefined, "Activateundefined".

The important part to recognize here is that jQuery has changed the `this` binding. In order to use a previous `this` binding, the value must be stored in a variable. A common name for storing this is `that`, `self`, `me`, or in best practice, an actual description of what `this` represents.

The reason saving the binding works is that the callback's execution context will be deeper in the execution context stack relative to where the binding value was saved, thus having access to that stored value.

*[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v5qr8/)*

```
$('#toggleButton').click(function(){
 var toggleBtn = this;
     //^ store this into the toggleBtn variable
 $("#toggleSet div").each(function(index,element){
                           //^ binds `this` to the current element
  if( element.innerHTML != "Skip" ){
       //^ we could have used `this.innerHTML` here
     $(element).toggleClass("Activate"+$(toggleBtn).data("color"));
                                        //^ re-use the stored `this` value
  }
 });
});
```