# How to replicate jQuery's $(this)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I am creating a mini-library, sort of trying to reconstruct, at least partly, the way `jQuery` works for learning purposes and to understand better how object-oriented programming works.

I have recreated the `jQuery` methods `click` and `addClass`, but when I call them like:

```
$(".class1").click(function() {
    $(".class1").addClass("class2"); // Works, but it adds class2 to all elements
    this.addClass("class2"); // Doesn't work
});
```

I get an `Uncaught Error` saying `this.addClass` is not a function, which is normal, since I shouldn't be able to access another object's methods.

**How is `$(this)` made in jQuery to mean the DOM element that triggered an event**, so that in my case I can use it to add `class2` only to the element clicked and not all elements that have the class `class1`?

P.S: *I tried reading the jQuery file, but I feel like these waters are currently too deep for me.*

---

**Edit**:

1. I always appreciate all the answers and the help I get on Stack Overflow, but telling me to use `$(this)` instead of `this` doesn't solve my issue, because `$(this)` doesn't exist in my code. I'm trying to learn how to create something like jQuery's `$(this)` & what's the logic behind it.
2. The `click` method is defined as follows:

```js
    $.prototype.click = function(callback) {
       for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
          this[i].onclick = function(event) {
             callback.call(this, event);
          }
       }
    };
```

Comment: Look up the function called `bind`.

Comment: FYI jQuery's source code is *terrible*. It's not a good example to learn from, or particularly easy to read even if you know what you're doing. (Generally, it's a horrible and overused library.)

Comment: @JeremyBanks I agree. When I read the jQuery source code I feel like knocking my head on the nearest wall. Even the commented unminified version is completely illegible for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an extra 1.5 years of experience, this question becomes rather easy.

1. Alter `$`, so that, except string selectors, it can accept `HTML` elements.
2. Create a new instance of the object containing the `HTML` element given.
3. Call `addClass` with that as the context.

**Code:**

```js
;(function() {
  /* The object constructor. */
  function ElementList(arg) {
    /* Cache the context. */
    var that = this;
    
    /* Save the length of the object. */
    this.length = 0;

    /* Check whether the argument is a string. */
    if (typeof arg == "string") {
      /* Fetch the elements matching the selector and inject them in 'this'. */
      [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(arg), function(element, index) {
        that[index] = element;
        that.length++;
      });
    }

    /* Check whether the argument is an HTML element and inject it into 'this'. */
    else if (arg instanceof Element) {
      this[0] = arg;
      this.length = 1;
    }
  }

  /* The 'click' method of the prototype. */
  ElementList.prototype.click = function(callback) {
    /* Iterate over every element and set the 'click' event. */
    [].forEach.call(this, function(element) {
      element.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        callback.call(this, event);
      });
    });
  }

  /* The 'addClass' method of the prototype. */
  ElementList.prototype.addClass = function(className) {
    /* Iterate over every element. */
    [].forEach.call(this, function(element) {
      /* Cache the classList of the element. */
      var list = element.classList;

      /* Add the specified className, if it doesn't already exist. */
      if (!list.contains(className)) list.add(className);
    });
  }

  /* The global callable. */
  window.$ = function(arg) {
    return new ElementList(arg);
  }
})();

/* Example */
$("#b1").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("clicked");
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<button id="b1">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or some combination of those to set the callback's context to the DOM Node. Here is a contrived example of jquery's `each` method that sets the context of the callback using `call`:

```
var $ = {
   each: function(selector, callback) {
      var collection = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
      collection.forEach(function(element, index) {
         // the magic...
         callback.call(element, index, element);
      });
   }
}

$.each('.foo', function(idx, el) {
   console.log(this.textContent);
});
```

Comment: `call`, `bind` and `apply` all set what `this` points to within a function ("context"). So if you want `this` to be something other than the current context (a function, object or window), then you use one of these methods to call the function with a particular context.

Comment: args are reversed in callback

Answer (score 1):

`this` is the native JavaScript element and only exposes the native API. You need to pass it to the jQuery constructor in order to access jQuery's API

```
$(this).addClass("class2"); // This will work
```

Comment: I don't use jQuery. I am trying to reconstruct it for learning purposes. The jQuery code is not present at all.

Comment: Uhm, what? Well that is going to highly depend on what decisions you made when recreating jQuery. Internally, for callbacks, jQuery will use `.apply(element)` in order to preserve the this state. I created a canonical question which explains how jQuery deals internally with `this`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173440/save-access-to-this-scope

Answer (score 0):

One possible way (only selectors are accepted):

```
$ = function(selector) {
    this.elements = '';//Select the element(s) based on your selector

    this.addClass = function(klass) {
        //apply your klass to you element(s)
        return this;
    };

    this.click= function(handler) {
        //Attach click event to your element(s)            
        return this;
    };

    return this;

};
```

Please keep in mind it's just an example.

**Edit 1:**

In your `click` method you are calling the handler in the wrong scope (the anonymous function scope). You need to use the outer scope:

```
$.prototype = {
    click: function(callback) {
        console.log(this.length);
        var _self = this;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this[i].onclick = function(event) {
                //this here presents the anonymous function scope
                //You need to call the handler in the outer scope
                callback.call(_self, event);
                //If you want to call the handler in the Element scope:
                //callback.call(_self[i], event); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** In your example, `this.addClass("class2");` doesn't work because jQuery calls the click handler in the `Element` scope not `jQuery` scope. Therefore, `this` presents the `Element` which dosen't have the `addClass` method;

Comment: I know why this doesn't work. I said it in my question as well. What I want to know is how to make my `$` object know which element having that class was clicked, so that when I call `$(".foo")click(function(){ $(this).addClass("foo2"))})`

Comment: `this` at the moment is an unidentified selector in my code when I use it inside the constructor `$()`.

Comment: Okey, I understand. Please show me how do you call the click handler ?

Comment: If you can add the `click` method source !

Comment: Check out my answer. Edit 1 :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand now your question. Let me try to help you again.

jQuery doesn't knows what DOM element do you use when you give it to selector. It doesn't parsing it or something else. Just save it to the internal property.

Very simplified code to understand:

```
$ = function(e) {

    // finding object. For example "this" is object
    if (typeof e !== 'object' || typeof e.className === 'undefined') {
        if (typeof e == 'string') {
            if (e[0] == '#') {
                e = document.getElementById(e.substring(1));
            } else if (e[0] == '.') {
                e = document.getElementsByClassName(e.substring(1))[0];
            } else {
                // ... etc
            }
        }
        // ... etc
    }

    var manager = {
        elem: e,
        addClass: function(newClass) {
            manager.elem.className = manager.elem.className + ' ' + newClass;
            return manager;
        },
        click: function(callback) {
            // here is just simple way without queues
            manager.elem.onclick = function(event) {
                callback.call(manager, event);
            }
        }
    }

    return manager;

}
```