# Getting variables value for an object instance using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, instances

I have this [code snippet from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS)

I then added a bit of my own code to attach a jQuery click event to a paragraph.

Maybe it is best to show the example:

```js
 function Person(first, last, age, gender, interests) {
      this.name = {
        'first': first,
        'last' : last
      };
      this.age = age;
      this.gen = gender;
      this.int = interests;
      this.nationality = "English";
      this.bio = function() {
        alert(this.name.first + ' ' + this.name.last + ' is ' + this.age + ' years old. He likes ' + this.int[0] + ' and ' + this.int[1] + '.');
      };
      this.greeting = function() {
        alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name.first + '.');
      };
      this.tt = function() {
        alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.gen + '.');
      };  
    
      this.init= function() {
        $("p").click(function(){
         alert('Hi!'); //works fine
          alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name.first + '.');//obj.html:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined
         }); 
      };
    
      this.init(); //Bind to the P tag using jQuery click event
    
    }
    var person1 = new Person('Bob', 'Smith', 32, 'male', ['music', 'skiing']);
    console.log(Person);
    person1.bio();
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
```

So when I click on the P element I get the alert Hi! followed by the uncaught error message.

How do I get the second alert to read, "Hi! I'm Bob"

Comment: this is pointing to jquery object which is p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve your problem. `this` keyword in JavaScript is tricky. The core of your problem is that the `this` is not what you think it is. See [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) for more details.

1) Cache the `this` into a variable in pervious scope.

```
this.init = function () {
  var self = this;
  $("p").click(function () {
    alert('Hi!');
    alert('Hi! I\'m ' + self.name.first + '.');
  });
};
```

2) bind `this` into the function that's being invoked

```
this.init = function () {
  var handleClick = function () {
    alert('Hi!');
    alert('Hi! I\'m ' + self.name.first + '.');
  };
  handleClick = handleClick.bind(this);
  $("p").click(handleClick);
};
```

Comment: Travis and Steven - Thanks to both! The reason I selected Stevens answer is it is easier for me to add var self=this;

Comment: @JimF - That's fine, perhaps this post will be informational for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24173441/1026459

Comment: Thanks for the link Travis. After a while it dawned on me $("p").click(function(){ did not have for example this.name defined due to a scope issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to retain the reference to the Person object, then you need to bind the jQuery callback function with the thisBinding.

```
this.init= function() {
     $("p").click(function(){
      alert('Hi!'); //works fine
      alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name.first + '.');
     }.bind(this));//binding this prevents the error
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `this` to the anonymous function you passed in jquery click() function.

```js
function Person(first, last, age, gender, interests) {
  this.name = {
    'first': first,
    'last' : last
  };
  this.age = age;
  this.gen = gender;
  this.int = interests;
  this.nationality = "English";
  this.bio = function() {
    alert(this.name.first + ' ' + this.name.last + ' is ' + this.age + ' years old. He likes ' + this.int[0] + ' and ' + this.int[1] + '.');
  };
  this.greeting = function() {
    alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name.first + '.');
  };
  this.tt = function() {
    alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.gen + '.');
  };  

  this.init= function() {
     $("p").click(function(){
      alert('Hi!'); //works fine
      alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name.first + '.');
     }.bind(this)); 
  };

  this.init(); //Bind to the P tag using jQuery click event

}
var person1 = new Person('Bob', 'Smith', 32, 'male', ['music', 'skiing']);
console.log(Person);
person1.bio();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to just declare a variable `name` outside the jquery function and use it inside the function

```
this.init = function() {
    var name = this.name;
    $("p").click(function(){
        alert('Hi!');
        alert('Hi! I\'m ' + name.first + '.');
    }); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using `this` for variables. `This, in your code refers to the`Person`instance. As soon as you create a new function`this`no longer references the`Person`function, but the`this.init`function, thus`Person` no longer exists in this context.

Rather user `var name...` when using variables, then you will be able to reference it in another context or function:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <script>
    function Person(first, last, age, gender, interests) {
      var name = {
        'first': first,
        'last' : last
      };
      var age = age;
      var gen = gender;
      var int = interests;
      var nationality = "English";
      this.bio = function() {
        alert(name.first + ' ' + name.last + ' is ' + age + ' years old. He likes ' + int[0] + ' and ' + int[1] + '.');
      };
      this.greeting = function() {
        alert('Hi! I\'m ' + name.first + '.');
      };
      this.tt = function() {
        alert('Hi! I\'m ' + gen + '.');
      };  
    
      this.init= function() {
        $("p").click(function(){
         alert('Hi!'); //works fine
          alert('Hi! I\'m ' + name.first + '.');//obj.html:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined
         }); 
      };
    
      this.init(); //Bind to the P tag using jQuery click event
    
    }
    var person1 = new Person('Bob', 'Smith', 32, 'male', ['music', 'skiing']);
    console.log(Person);
    person1.bio();
    </script> 
    </body>
    </html>
```